# autocomplete on click updates the same value on second input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone plz help me out here as most of the things looks ok like fetching matching results from database but then when i click on value on both input box the same autocomplete value gets added.

could someone please help me fix this issue?

here is my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="form-label-outside">From</label>
        <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-inline">
        <input id="from-input" class="form-input" name="from" type="text">
        <div id="from-show-list" class="list-group"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="form-label-outside">To</label>
    <div class="form-wrap form-wrap-inline">
        <input id="to-input" class="form-input"  name="to" type="text">
        <div id="to-show-list" class="list-group"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my js

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#from-input").keyup(function() {
            let searchText = $(this).val();
            if (searchText != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "airports.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        query: searchText,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#from-show-list").html(response);
                    },
                });
            } else {
                $("#from-show-list").html("");
            }
        });
        // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
        $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
            $("#from-input").val($(this).text());
            $("#from-show-list").html("");
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#to-input").keyup(function() {
            let searchText = $(this).val();
            if (searchText != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "airports.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        query: searchText,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#to-show-list").html(response);
                    },
                });
            } else {
                $("#to-show-list").html("");
            }
        });
        // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
        $(document).on("click", "a", function() {
            $("#to-input").val($(this).text());
            $("#to-show-list").html("");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the php

```
require_once 'includes/config.php';

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $inpText = $_POST['query'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM pt_flights_airports WHERE cityName LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR code LIKE ?';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$inpText.'%','%'.$inpText.'%','%'.$inpText.'%'));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-1">'.$row['cityName'].' ('.$row['code'].') - <small>'.$row['name'].'</small></a>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p class="list-group-item  border-1">Airport not listed!</p>';
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Please give a clear explanation for the question

Comment: #Zia what is currently happening. i have 2 inputfields as you can see. say i type something on either of the input field then from database suggestion shows. now nomatter im on whichever input filed 1 or maybe 2 if i click on a value which gets suggested from database on click the same value gets entered on both the input field whereas i want different values for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises due to the click function on link.  Define two separate groups of links by specifying the id of the div that contains those links.

```
    // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
    $(document).on("click", "#from-show-list a", function() {
        $("#from-input").val($(this).text());
        $("#from-show-list").html("");
    });

    // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
    $(document).on("click", "#to-show-list a", function() {
        $("#to-input").val($(this).text());
        $("#to-show-list").html("");
    });
```

Apply max height to the results div using css like this.

```
<div id="from-show-list" class="list-group" style="max-height: 100px;  overflow: auto;"></div>
<div id="to-show-list" class="list-group" style="max-height: 100px;  overflow: auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much @T Shah. i have one last issue how can i make it scroll as of now its flooding all my page if there are too many results. would appreciate if can help with this too.

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.  You can change the max height to suit your layout.

Comment: Thanks alot @T Shah really appreciate your time and help. you saved me from a huge headache.